# Replica Set Question - one primary instance with two secondary instances

Tags: database-design, replication, mongodb

Running on AWS ubuntu 16.04 and the primary is a local ubuntu 16.04 on local vm.

When watching the log, I noticed that the primary will switch to secondary whenever a secondary comes online to let the secondary sync, then it will switch back to primary.

is there a way to stop that? This seems worrisome as I am already setting priority to 0 on secondary instances. I need primary to be write to access at all times - I can't have it switch to secondary in case one of the secondary fails and has to reconnect.

Here is what the config looks like:

```js
rs.config()
{
  "_id" : "dbname",
  "version" : 11,
  "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
  "members" : [
    {
      "_id" : 0,
      "host" : "Primary",
      "arbiterOnly" : false,
      "buildIndexes" : true,
      "hidden" : false,
      "priority" : 1,
      "tags" : {

      },
      "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
      "votes" : 1
    },
    {
      "_id" : 1,
      "host" : "Secondary",
      "arbiterOnly" : false,
      "buildIndexes" : true,
      "hidden" : false,
      "priority" : 0,
      "tags" : {

      },
      "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
      "votes" : 1
    },
    {
      "_id" : 2,
      "host" : "Secondary",
      "arbiterOnly" : false,
      "buildIndexes" : true,
      "hidden" : false,
      "priority" : 0,
      "tags" : {

      },
      "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
      "votes" : 1
    }
  ],
  "settings" : {
    "chainingAllowed" : true,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
    "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
    "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
    "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
    "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
    "getLastErrorModes" : {

    },
    "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
      "w" : 1,
      "wtimeout" : 0
    },
    "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("someid")
  }
}
```

also here is the full log from the primary

```
2018-02-01T09:20:02.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=19294 port=27017 dbpath=/srv/mongodb/db0 64-bit host=ubuntu-cheftest
2018-02-01T09:20:02.984-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.2
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,192.168.6.39", port: 27017 }, replication: { replSet: "mdblid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/srv/mongodb/db0" } }
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /srv/mongodb/db0 created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-02-01T09:20:02.985-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=488M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-02-01T09:20:03.677-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1517505603:677241][19294:0x7f156a0f69c0], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 71/8704
2018-02-01T09:20:03.882-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1517505603:882098][19294:0x7f156a0f69c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 71 through 72
2018-02-01T09:20:03.991-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1517505603:991545][19294:0x7f156a0f69c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 72 through 72
2018-02-01T09:20:04.136-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Starting WiredTigerRecordStoreThread local.oplog.rs
2018-02-01T09:20:04.136-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] The size storer reports that the oplog contains 4572 records totaling to 503638 bytes
2018-02-01T09:20:04.136-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Scanning the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation
2018-02-01T09:20:04.149-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-01T09:20:04.149-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-02-01T09:20:04.150-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-02-01T09:20:04.150-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2018-02-01T09:20:04.150-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-01T09:20:04.150-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-01T09:20:04.150-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2018-02-01T09:20:04.150-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-02-01T09:20:04.150-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-01T09:20:04.150-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2018-02-01T09:20:04.150-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-02-01T09:20:04.150-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-01T09:20:04.205-0800 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/srv/mongodb/db0/diagnostic.data'
2018-02-01T09:20:04.208-0800 I REPL     [initandlisten] No oplog entries to apply for recovery. appliedThrough and checkpointTimestamp are both null.
2018-02-01T09:20:04.209-0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2018-02-01T09:20:04.239-0800 W NETWORK  [replexec-0] Failed to connect to 172.31.28.232:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.269-0800 W NETWORK  [replexec-0] Failed to connect to 172.31.24.194:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.269-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] New replica set config in use: { _id: "mdblid", version: 11, protocolVersion: 1, members: [ { _id: 0, host: "192.168.6.39:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 }, { _id: 2, host: "mongo3:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 0.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 }, { _id: 3, host: "mongo2:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 0.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 } ], settings: { chainingAllowed: true, heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000, heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10, electionTimeoutMillis: 10000, catchUpTimeoutMillis: -1, catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis: 30000, getLastErrorModes: {}, getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 }, replicaSetId: ObjectId('5a68d17b6bae4407d0183a21') } }
2018-02-01T09:20:04.269-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] This node is 192.168.6.39:27017 in the config
2018-02-01T09:20:04.269-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] transition to STARTUP2 from STARTUP
2018-02-01T09:20:04.269-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] Starting replication storage threads
2018-02-01T09:20:04.270-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo2:27017
2018-02-01T09:20:04.273-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo3:27017
2018-02-01T09:20:04.274-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] transition to RECOVERING from STARTUP2
2018-02-01T09:20:04.274-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] Starting replication fetcher thread
2018-02-01T09:20:04.274-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] Starting replication applier thread
2018-02-01T09:20:04.274-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] Starting replication reporter thread
2018-02-01T09:20:04.278-0800 I REPL     [rsSync] transition to SECONDARY from RECOVERING
2018-02-01T09:20:04.303-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to mongo2:27017 - HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.303-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to mongo2:27017 due to failed operation on a connection
2018-02-01T09:20:04.304-0800 I REPL_HB  [replexec-1] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 1) to mongo2:27017, response status: HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.304-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to mongo3:27017 - HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.304-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to mongo3:27017 due to failed operation on a connection
2018-02-01T09:20:04.304-0800 I REPL_HB  [replexec-0] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 3) to mongo3:27017, response status: HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.304-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo2:27017
2018-02-01T09:20:04.304-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo3:27017
2018-02-01T09:20:04.334-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to mongo2:27017 - HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.334-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to mongo2:27017 due to failed operation on a connection
2018-02-01T09:20:04.334-0800 I REPL_HB  [replexec-1] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 5) to mongo2:27017, response status: HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.334-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to mongo3:27017 - HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.334-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to mongo3:27017 due to failed operation on a connection
2018-02-01T09:20:04.334-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo2:27017
2018-02-01T09:20:04.334-0800 I REPL_HB  [replexec-2] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 7) to mongo3:27017, response status: HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.335-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo3:27017
2018-02-01T09:20:04.365-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to mongo3:27017 - HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.365-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to mongo3:27017 due to failed operation on a connection
2018-02-01T09:20:04.365-0800 I REPL_HB  [replexec-0] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 11) to mongo3:27017, response status: HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.365-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] Member mongo3:27017 is now in state RS_DOWN
2018-02-01T09:20:04.365-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to mongo2:27017 - HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.365-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to mongo2:27017 due to failed operation on a connection
2018-02-01T09:20:04.365-0800 I REPL_HB  [replexec-2] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 9) to mongo2:27017, response status: HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-02-01T09:20:04.366-0800 I REPL     [replexec-2] Member mongo2:27017 is now in state RS_DOWN
2018-02-01T09:20:05.656-0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.31.28.232:56742 #1 (1 connection now open)
2018-02-01T09:20:05.686-0800 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 172.31.28.232:56742 (0 connections now open)
2018-02-01T09:20:05.718-0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.31.28.232:56746 #2 (1 connection now open)
2018-02-01T09:20:05.719-0800 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 172.31.28.232:56746 conn: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication", version: "3.6.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.04" } }
2018-02-01T09:20:07.782-0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.31.24.194:39638 #3 (2 connections now open)
2018-02-01T09:20:07.812-0800 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 172.31.24.194:39638 (1 connection now open)
2018-02-01T09:20:07.846-0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.31.24.194:39642 #4 (2 connections now open)
2018-02-01T09:20:07.847-0800 I NETWORK  [conn4] received client metadata from 172.31.24.194:39642 conn: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication", version: "3.6.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.04" } }
2018-02-01T09:20:09.365-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo2:27017
2018-02-01T09:20:09.365-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo3:27017
2018-02-01T09:20:09.426-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Successfully connected to mongo2:27017, took 61ms (1 connections now open to mongo2:27017)
2018-02-01T09:20:09.427-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Successfully connected to mongo3:27017, took 62ms (1 connections now open to mongo3:27017)
2018-02-01T09:20:09.456-0800 I REPL     [replexec-2] Member mongo3:27017 is now in state SECONDARY
2018-02-01T09:20:09.459-0800 I REPL     [replexec-1] Member mongo2:27017 is now in state SECONDARY
2018-02-01T09:20:15.302-0800 I REPL     [replexec-1] Starting an election, since we've seen no PRIMARY in the past 10000ms
2018-02-01T09:20:15.302-0800 I REPL     [replexec-1] conducting a dry run election to see if we could be elected. current term: 41
2018-02-01T09:20:15.332-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] VoteRequester(term 41 dry run) received a yes vote from mongo3:27017; response message: { term: 41, voteGranted: true, reason: "", ok: 1.0, operationTime: Timestamp(1517505592, 1), $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1517505592, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } }
2018-02-01T09:20:15.332-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] dry election run succeeded, running for election in term 42
2018-02-01T09:20:15.333-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Ending connection to host mongo2:27017 due to bad connection status; 0 connections to that host remain open
2018-02-01T09:20:15.334-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo2:27017
2018-02-01T09:20:15.365-0800 I REPL     [replexec-1] VoteRequester(term 42) received a yes vote from mongo3:27017; response message: { term: 42, voteGranted: true, reason: "", ok: 1.0, operationTime: Timestamp(1517505592, 1), $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1517505592, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } }
2018-02-01T09:20:15.365-0800 I REPL     [replexec-1] election succeeded, assuming primary role in term 42
2018-02-01T09:20:15.365-0800 I REPL     [replexec-1] transition to PRIMARY from SECONDARY
2018-02-01T09:20:15.366-0800 I REPL     [replexec-1] Entering primary catch-up mode.
2018-02-01T09:20:15.366-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo2:27017
2018-02-01T09:20:15.395-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Successfully connected to mongo2:27017, took 61ms (2 connections now open to mongo2:27017)
2018-02-01T09:20:15.426-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] Caught up to the latest optime known via heartbeats after becoming primary.
2018-02-01T09:20:15.426-0800 I REPL     [replexec-0] Exited primary catch-up mode.
2018-02-01T09:20:15.434-0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Successfully connected to mongo2:27017, took 67ms (2 connections now open to mongo2:27017)
2018-02-01T09:20:17.282-0800 I REPL     [rsSync] transition to primary complete; database writes are now permitted
2018-02-01T09:20:18.849-0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.31.24.194:39646 #5 (3 connections now open)
2018-02-01T09:20:18.850-0800 I NETWORK  [conn5] received client metadata from 172.31.24.194:39646 conn: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS", version: "3.6.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.04" } }
2018-02-01T09:20:18.970-0800 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.31.24.194:39648 #6 (4 connections now open)
2018-02-01T09:20:18.971-0800 I NETWORK  [conn6] received client metadata from 172.31.24.194:39648 conn: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS", version: "3.6.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.04" } }
```

Comment: It sounds that you have understood something wrong. When secondary comes online and it is behind primary (need to sync), primary don't change status to the secondary. There is always one primary elected at replica set. Situation where there are only secondary/recovering nodes at replica set, don't exists.

Comment: Can you share more details: Where are your secondaries hosted in relation to your local primary? If you have a 3 member replica set, the primary will need to have healthy network connectivity with at least one other member of the replica set to maintain a majority (2/3 configured members). What specific version of MongoDB are you using (output of `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell)? Can you share the output of `rs.conf()` and the log lines you've mentioned when the primary switches to a secondary? There may be relevant log lines on the former primary as well as the secondary that rejoined.

Comment: 2018-01-31T17:18:26.141+0000 I ASIO [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Successfully connected to "Primary", took 61ms (1 connections now open to "Primary")
2018-01-31T17:18:26.172+0000 I REPL [replexec-2] Member "primary" is now in state SECONDARY

db version is 3.6.2

Comment: Where are your secondaries hosted? The current description mentions a primary in a local VM and at least one secondary on AWS. Also, what sort of networking do you have between replica set members? For example, is your local VM connected to AWS directly or via VPN/SSH/port forwarding/... ? Is your primary VM connecting via NAT or bridged networking? If your primary becomes isolated from a majority of the replica set members it is expected to step down, so my suspicion is that the behaviour you are seeing is related to network connectivity. Try grepping for relevant log lines mentioning `REPL`.

Comment: @Lidor Soikher, As "Stennie" has already told that like where is your secondaries are hosted. On the same Data center premises .As per my understanding definitely you have one secondary replica to other center.

Comment: Hello all and thank you for all the info, we have the ips reducted by the way. 3 different hosts otherwise it would error out. As far as location one local and two secondary on aws using vpn to allow them to see each other as if they were local resources. However is the step down process from the primary in order to sync a must ?

Comment: Could you paste in an excerpt from the log(s) to show us how the primary is temporarily stepping down when the secondary comes online?

Comment: If so then wouldn't it lock up my tables every time secndarys went out of sync ?

Comment: Thanks for adding the MongoDB log information. That confirms the election is expected due to networking connectivity between the members of your replica set. I'll add a more detailed explanation.

Comment: do you think making the secondary ones hidden would help in this ? or are hidden secondary still going to have primary step down at some initial point for sync?

Comment: As noted in my answer, the underlying issue for your observed behaviour is the voting configuration for your replica set. Up to you if you'd like to [make the secondaries hidden](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/) as well: this will prevent reads from a driver or application using a replica set connection with secondary read preferences. It's still possible to directly connect to hidden secondaries if you want to use these for backups or reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your current replica set configuration, this behaviour is expected.

In order to [be elected (and remain) primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/), a replica set member must have connectivity with a majority of voting replica set members.

Your configuration has two members which have [`priority 0`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-priority-0-member/) and cannot be elected as primary, so there is only one candidate for primary (the member `_id:0` ). However, all of the members in your replica set are voting so the required majority to elect a primary is 2/3 configured replica set members.

Based on the log information you have provided from the member you prefer as primary, the [replica set member state](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-states/) timeline looks like:

- Member with `_id: 0` is started and performs WiredTiger consistency checks for the data files. The `mongod` transitions from replica set STARTUP (reading configuration) to STARTUP2 (enabling replication threads).
- STARTUP2 completes and the member briefly transitions to RECOVERING and then SECONDARY state, where it is now ready to connect to other members of the replica set based on the last saved replica set configuration.
- Network connectivity to the other members is not available (`Connection refused`), so the member transitions into a SECONDARY state and marks the other members of the replica set as unreachable: `Member mongo2:27017 is now in state RS_DOWN`. Since there is only 1 voting member available out of the 3 configured, a primary cannot be elected so this member will remain SECONDARY and will not propose an election.
- When network connectivity issues are resolved, the status of other members of the replica set can now be determined: `Member mongo2:27017 is now in state SECONDARY`.
- The replica set now has connectivity between enough members to start an election. The reason for the election is also noted: `Starting an election, since we've seen no PRIMARY in the past 10000ms`.
- The election succeeds (`election succeeded, assuming primary role in term 42`) and this member transitions from SECONDARY to PRIMARY state.

> I need primary to be write to access at all times - I can't have it switch to secondary in case one of the secondary fails and has to reconnect.

The default configuration for a replica set is designed for automatic failover: if the current primary becomes isolated from a majority of replica set members, a new primary can be elected to continue write availability.

If you do not want automatic failover, set the votes for your secondaries to 0:

```
var conf=rs.conf()
conf.members[1].votes = 0
conf.members[2].votes = 0
rs.reconfig(conf)
```

With only one voting member in the replica set configuration, the primary is now able to elect itself irrespective of the connectivity or health of the other replica set members.

There are a few obvious caveats with this configuration:

- Since you only have a single voting node, a [`w:majority` write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/) is equivalent to `w:1` and will only request acknowledgement from the primary.
- If the primary remains disconnected from the other replica set members for any significant duration, the secondaries may become stale and [require a full resync](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/). You can mitigate this by [increasing the size of the replication oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/) for each of your replica set members in order to provide an appropriate buffer.

Comment: I have changed the votes to 0 as you recommended, once member 1 and 2 go offline, member 0 continuously tries to connect to them. I know this is default and wanted behavior but would that interfere with it's activity ?

Comment: @LidorSoikher Yes, it is expected that your replica set members will try to reestablish network connections and resume syncing. Aside from noise in logs, that shouldn't interfere with normal activity. If you plan to have your secondaries unreachable more often than not, another approach to consider would be using [Mongo Connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20MongoDB) or a similar non-default replication solution. Mongo Connector also relies on the replication oplog (similar to a secondary), but only syncs when the connector is running.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your "Secondary" hosts names!  You cannot have TWO nodes with same name "Secondary", because that name is "resolved" to IP address and now (from Primarys point of view) there is two nodes what have same IP address. Please build your configuration using IP addresses (or unique hostnames) as "host" information.

Take that rs.conf() document to text editor, change "host" information and then at PRIMARY node go to `admin` database and give command [rs.reconfig( 
 paste here your conf-document )](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfig/)

Comment: I assume the hostnames were redacted in the `rs.conf()` information. Trying to add members with duplicate hostnames and ports should result in an error message similar to `Found two member configurations with same host field`.